# How difficult will it be to determine, get and apply latest patches to Solaris 8

Tags: solaris, patch

I have a Sun Ultra Enterprise 2 running Solaris 8 (Generic_108528-11). This hasn't had any patches applied for years. I just now got the configuration right for connecting to the internet through my Verizon router. I want to get an uptodate browser (it's currently running Netscape 4.76!) but I suspect that I'll need to have the latest (or perhaps the last) patches created for Solaris 8 applied in order to have a current browser work. How difficult will it be to determine what patches I need and the get and apply them?
I've considered upgrading to a newer version of Solaris but I don't think any newer version that will run on this box is available on CD; everything is on DVD and I don't even know if I could replace the CD-ROM drive with a DVD drive.
I'm pretty much a novice when it come to Solaris or Unix when it comes to administration.

Comment: FYI: Probably the CD drive is SCSI, you can get SCSI DVD drives. Easiest way to find out would be to open the case and look...

Comment: Thanks derobert. I know it's SCSI. The question is whether or not a SCSI DVD drive will operate when connected to this box. Perhaps the fact that it's SCSI means that the fact that DVD didn't exist when this box was designed doesn't matter.

Comment: no particular experience with that system, but SCSI DVD drives speak the same protocol and are the same device class as CD drives. You may need adapters, of course, depending on the SCSI physical interfaces involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're paying for a support contract, it should be very easy to download the latest Solaris 8 recommended patch bundle from the Oracle Support website and install it using the included script & instructions in that bundle.

Oracle does not make Solaris 8 patches available without paying for a support contract, and is scheduled to stop producing Solaris 8 patches in October 2014 (over 14 years from when the OS was first released in February 2000), but will
still charge for access to get existing patches after that date.

Comment: OK @alanc. I'm beginning to wonder if I'm wasting my time trying to make use of this box. If I can't update the current OS or install a new one, what's the point? I guess Oracle can't give away Solaris 8 patches if they have customers who are paying for them.

Comment: @Tom there is a Debian sparc port, if you just want to use the hardware. Not too useful if the goal is to learn Solaris, though.

Comment: You could try installing Solaris 9, but it may be a frustrating [experience](http://www.rainsbrook.co.uk/sun/Sun-e2/). You would still need to pay for patches though. The hardware could well run for a while. they were built really well.